# http2 requests are stalled in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, express, xmlhttprequest, http2, spdy

I have a Node.js web server that uses [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [spdy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy) to serve RESTful API endpoints over http2. As you can see from the screenshot attached, some of my requests are getting stalled from 15 to 20 seconds and it only happens in Chrome.

The entire reason we upgraded to http2 was so that we didn't have to do domain sharding to avoid the queuing wait times. Is there any way I can overcome this? I also have the HTTP2_SESSION logs from Chrome's network-internals tool if those would be helpful.

Here's the screenshot of the absurd amount of stalled time, which is accounting for **80%** of our total time:

[image]

**EDIT**:

The npm package is called SPDY. It still uses HTTP/2. I couldn't get Node.js' native http2 module working with express.

**EDIT 2**:

[Paste bin link to the http2 session logs](https://pastebin.com/WXMgunNz)

```
<a href="https://pastebin.com/WXMgunNz"></a>
```

Comment: Hmm. SPDY is deprecated and SPDY is not HTTP/2. In fact, Google dumped SPDY in 2016

Comment: @Rob Right. The spdy package now uses HTTP/2. It's an HTTP/2 connection.

Comment: Add the HTTP2 session logs please

Comment: @BarryPollard added

Comment: Hmmm. Can’t see anything there. Just seems a long time before Chrome decides to send it. Upgrading Chrome to ensure on latest version is all o can suggest.

Comment: @BarryPollard Upgrading chrome seems to fix it, but this isn't an acceptable solution, as we can't force clients to update browsers. I guess we'll have no choice but to move away from HTTP/2. Sigh...

Comment: Wonder if it's an instance of this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=723748. Either way can't offer anything except to not use HTTP/2 or wait until most users have upgraded (Chrome auto upgrades but do know some companies turn that off at policy level).

Comment: seeing similar on latest chrome, 88.0.4324.192, every now and then there's roughly 10 seconds of stalled time getting static files from a cloudfront distro, no other tabs and i'm just requesting a single resource.  if I update cloudfront to only use http 1 and 1.1 it seems to go away.

Comment: @ronpastore did you find a way around your issue? I'm seeing a similar problem.

Comment: we did, our VPN software had a bug, the issue resolved when we moved to ZScaler.